# Prove that for every nonempty family of F of sets,$\cap_{A \in F}\subseteq \cup_{A \in F}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that for every nonempty family of F of sets,$\cap_{A \in F}\subseteq \cup_{A \in F}$.

I am very confused with this notation and cannot figure out how to prove this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In words, what do you think is being asked?

Comment: If $x\in\cap_{A\in F}$, then for all $A\in F$ you have that $x\in A$. If $F$ is not empty, in particular this means that there is some $A\in F$ such that $x\in A$. It follows that $x\in\cup_{A\in F}$. Therefore, $\cap_{A\in F}\subset \cup_{A\in F}$.

Comment: On the notation, $\cap_{A\in F}$ likely means $\cap_{A\in F}A$ and $\cup_{A\in F}$, means $\cup_{A\in F}A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sets involved in this problem.

The first one is $$ \cap_{A \in F}$$ and the second on is  $$\cup_{A \in F}$$

What you want to show is that the first set is a subset of the second set.

In order to prove that we need to show that every element of  $$ \cap_{A \in F}$$ is also an element of  $$\cup_{A \in F}$$

Let  $$x\in \cap_{A \in F}$$ Then for every $ A \in F$,  $x\in A $

Pick an arbitrary $A \in F$.

We know that $$ A\subseteq \cup_{A \in F}$$

Since $x\in A$ and $ A\subseteq \cup_{A \in F}$ we have $$x\in \cup_{A \in F}$$

Which proves $$\cap_{A \in F}\subseteq \cup_{A \in F}$$